# What is an effective way to search world-wide location names with ElasticSearch?

Tags: search, location, elasticsearch

I have location information provided by [GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) parsed into a relational database. Using this information, I am attempting to build an ElasticSearch index that contains populated place (city) names, administrative division (state, province, etc.) names, country names and country codes. My goal is to provide a location search that is similar to Google Maps':

[image: Google Maps]

I don't need the cool bold highlighting, but I do need the search to return similar results in a similar way. I've tried creating a mapping with a single location field consisting of the entire location name (e.g., "Round Rock, TX, United States") and I've also tried having five separate fields consisting of each piece of a location. I've tried keyword and prefix queries and edgengram analyzers; I have been unsuccessful in finding the correct configuration to get this working properly.

What kinds of analyzers--both index and search--should I be looking at to accomplish my goals? This search doesn't have to be as perfected as Google's but I'd like it to be at least similar.

I do want to support partial-name matches, which is why I've been fiddling with edgengram. For example, a search of "round r" should match Round Rock, TX, United States. Also, I would prefer that results whose populated place (city) names begin with the exact search term be ranked higher than other results. For example, a search of "round ro" should match Round Rock, TX, United States before Round, Some Province, RO (Romania). I hope I've made this clear enough.

Here is my current index configuration (this is an anonymous type in C# that is later serialized to JSON and passed to the ElasticSearch API):

```
settings = new
{
    index = new
    {
        number_of_shards = 1,
        number_of_replicas = 0,
        refresh_interval = -1,
        analysis = new
        {
            analyzer = new
            {
                edgengram_index_analyzer = new
                {
                    type = "custom",
                    tokenizer = "index_tokenizer",
                    filter = new[] { "lowercase", "asciifolding" },
                    char_filter = new[] { "no_commas_char_filter" },
                    stopwords = new object[0]
                },
                search_analyzer = new
                {
                    type = "custom",
                    tokenizer = "standard",
                    filter = new[] { "lowercase", "asciifolding" },
                    char_filter = new[] { "no_commas_char_filter" },
                    stopwords = new object[0]
                }
            },
            tokenizer = new
            {
                index_tokenizer = new
                {
                    type = "edgeNGram",
                    min_gram = 1,
                    max_gram = 100
                }
            },
            char_filter = new
            {
                no_commas_char_filter = new
                {
                    type = "mapping",
                    mappings = new[] { ",=>" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
mappings = new
{
    location = new
    {
        _all = new { enabled = false },
        properties = new
        {
            populatedPlace = new { index_analyzer = "edgengram_index_analyzer", type = "string" },
            administrativeDivision = new { index_analyzer = "edgengram_index_analyzer", type = "string" },
            administrativeDivisionAbbreviation = new { index_analyzer = "edgengram_index_analyzer", type = "string" },
            country = new { index_analyzer = "edgengram_index_analyzer", type = "string" },
            countryCode = new { index_analyzer = "edgengram_index_analyzer", type = "string" },
            population = new { type = "long" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: karmi on #elasticsearch IRC suggested I should look into the experimental "suggester" feature in ElasticSearch. Suggesters seem to work better than prefix queries or edgengrams for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
  "analysis": {
    "tokenizer": {
      "name_tokenizer": {
        "type": "edgeNGram",
        "max_gram": 100,
        "min_gram": 2,
        "side": "front"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "name_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "type": "custom",
        "filter": ["lowercase", "multi_words", "name_filter"]
      },
    },
    "filter": {
      "multi_words": {
        "type": "shingle",
        "min_shingle_size": 2,
        "max_shingle_size": 10
      },
      "name_filter": {
        "type": "edgeNGram",
        "max_gram": 100,
        "min_gram": 2,
        "side": "front"
      },          
    }
  }
```

I think using `name_analyzer` will replicate the google search that you are talking about. You can tweak the configuration a bit to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to compare this to a suggester implementation. BTW, `side` is deprecated in the latest ES build.

Comment: I ended up going with the completion suggester. I'm not really sure if I'm using it correctly but it was pretty easy to get this kind of search working with it.

Comment: ok, yeah, `suggester` seems the apt. solution to you. The one I provided is pretty old when `suggester` wasn't added in elasticsearch. And as you correctly pointed out `side` is deprecated. `edgeNgram`, now, by default takes the `side` as `front`