# Can't deal with accents in Elasticsearch indexing and search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue with elasticsearch and the way the data are indexed/retrieved. I don't understand what happens.

This is the mapping I use (sorry, it's yaml format) :
The idea is simple, in theory... I have a string analyzer with lowercase and asciifolding filters. I don't want to care about case or accents, and I would like to use this analyzer to index and search.

```
settings:
    index:
        analysis:
            filter:
                autocomplete_filter:
                    type: edgeNGram
                    side: front
                    min_gram: 1
                    max_gram: 20
            analyzer:
                autocomplete:
                    type: custom
                    tokenizer: standard
                    filter: [lowercase, asciifolding, autocomplete_filter]
                string_analyzer:
                    type:        custom
                    tokenizer:   standard
                    filter:      [lowercase, asciifolding]
types:
    city:
        mappings:
            cityName:
                type: string
                analyzer: string_analyzer
                search_analyzer: string_analyzer
            location: {type: geo_point}
```

When I run this query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix":{
            "cityName":"per"
        }
    }
    ,
    "size":20
}
```

I get some results like "Perpezat", "Pern", "Péreuil" which is the excepted result.

But if I run the following query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix":{
            "cityName":"pér"
        }
    }
    ,
    "size":20
}
```

Then I get no result at all.

If you have any clue or help, I would be happy to know it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mario-trucco Finally, I've found this post that explains a better way to analyze the strings.

[What is an effective way to search world-wide location names with ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124356/what-is-an-effective-way-to-search-world-wide-location-names-with-elasticsearch)

Of course it doesn't answer my initial question and I still don't understand what happened, but it solves my problem by removing it.

Thanks again for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Prefix Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html), your search input is not analyzed like in other cases:

> Matches documents that have fields containing terms with a specified prefix (**not analyzed**)

Your first example works because the documents are analyzed at index time  using your analyzer with lowercase and asciifolding, so they contain a term starting with `per` (`perpezat`, `pern`, `pereuil`).

Your second example does not work because those documents don't contain any terms starting with `pér`.

Since I couldn't find a way to tell Elasticsearch to analyze the prefix before performing the search, you could achieve your goal by manually adding this step:

1. Ask Elastisearch to analyze your input calling the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#indices-analyze)
2. Use the output from step 1 (it should be `per` in the examples) for the prefix query

For this to work, your search input should be a single term (I think that could be why Elasticsearch doesn't want to analyze it in the first place)

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I've also tried with Match query, Wildcard (which is like Prefix I think) and StringQuery.
Whatever the query, I just want to retrieve the "names that start by * "

Comment: @billy59 Match query should return "Perpezat", "Pern", "Péreuil" also with you use "pér" as input, but it returns everything that contains the term, non just that starts with. Are you planning to try the manual approach that I suggested?

Comment: should return "Perpezat", "Pern", "Péreuil" also with you use "pér" as input
> actually, it doesn't. That's the problem.

Yes, I'm going to try to call the analyzer API if it's the unique solution.
I just wondered if I did something bad

Comment: @billy59 Very strange.. I really expected `GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "cityName" : "pér"
        }
    }
}` to work (except for the prefix part). Maybe there is some other issue, for example the mapping created after indexing the documents (it always needs to be done before)

Comment: Actually after a test, `"query": { "match" : { "cityName" : "per"}}` doesn't return any result as well.
There's probably something wrong with my mapping

Comment: But this query `{"tokenizer" : "standard", "filter" : ["lowercase", "asciifolding"], "text" : "Pérenchies"}` to the Analyzer API returns the following result. That seems to be good :

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "perenchies",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 10,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}

Comment: @billy59 have you tried `GET /{index}/_mapping/city` to see if it's what you expected? If it is, are you positive that data have been indexed after creating the mapping?

Comment: It looks fine to me : `"mappings" : {"city" : {"properties" : {"cityName" : {"type" : "string","analyzer" : "string_analyzer"},"location" : {"type" : "geo_point"}}}`

And yes, the data have been indexed after. I mean, I use the FosElasticaBundle in a Symfony project. And I ran again and again the populate command, which reset and reindex all datas.

I'm gonna try to remove completely the index and check again.
I know it looks like an obvious stupid mistake. That's why I'm getting mad.
Thanks again.